# Find records that were created closest to the current date

Tags: activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I would like to get the records that have their `created_at` date closest to the current date. How can I do this with active records' `where` clause?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could find the closest record in the past with something like:

```
Record.where("created_at <= ?", Date.today).order_by("created_at DESC").limit(1)
```

Similarly, you can have the closest record in the future

```
Record.where("created_at >= ?", Date.today).order_by("created_at ASC").limit(1)
```

And then compare wich one is the closest to current date...

There may be a solution to do it with a single request, but I could not find how (if you're using SQL server, there's a method DATEDIFF that could help).

**Update**: *Thanks to Mischa*

If you're sure that all `created_at`are in the past, you're looking to the last created record, that could be written

```
Record.order("created_at").last
```

**Update**

To get all the records created the same date then the last record:

```
last_record_date = Record.max(:created_at)
Record.where(:created_at => (last_record_date.at_beginning_of_day)..(last_record_date.end_of_day))
```

Comment: In theory it's possible to have a `created_date` in the future, but it won't happen if you use Rails' automatic timestamps. So you you can just leave out the `where` clause. Using `order_by("created_at DESC")` should be enough.

Comment: @Mischa You're so right! I've written the answer thinking it could be any date, and changed to `created_at` when I read the question again, without thinking it simplifies the solution. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks Baldrick I was thinking to get the records that are the closest to todays date, not sorting them but filtering them. So something along the lines of MIN(Date(created_at) - Date.today). Know what I mean?

Comment: @chell I've update my answer to get all the records created the same date then the last record.

Comment: Thanks that looks like exactly what I Need. I have accepted your answer and also added a point. Thanks again.