# MongoDB - Find record that has a date closest to the query date

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have a Collection containing a datetime field. I want to fetch a single record which has the closest date less than the date I input as search query. Something like this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12294272/find-records-that-were-created-closest-to-the-current-date), but for MongoDB/Mongoose. Like `MIN(Date(_created_at) - <queryDate>)`.

As of now I have been using the following query to achieve the above logic, but I was looking for a more cleaner solution as I can not limit the number of records. Possibly using **distinct** option. Also I would like to avoid using the **aggregate** framework, if possible.

```
 db.cm_data.find({
     "_p_user": "_User$peyi3uzZdZ",
     "_created_at": {
         "$lte": ISODate(<queryDate>)
     }
 }).sort({
     "_created_at": -1
 }).limit(1);
```

Comment: You want to select a **single** record, yet you say you *can not* limit the number of records. Meaning?

Comment: I have to get a single record per user that has the `_created_at` field closest to the query date. But as there are multiple users, I can not limit the query in that way

Comment: Okay, Single record **per user** is the objective. You should have posted a sample record for us to understand the schema. Anyway, so what I understand here is, that `cm_data` has multiple records associated with each user, and you want to select only one record (from the input date) for each user, correct?